# ERROR while installing @skyscanner/backpack-react-scripts v10.4.0

Tags: reactjs, skyscanner

I am trying to install this,

```
npx create-react-app@3.4.1 my-app --scripts-version=@skyscanner/backpack-react-scripts --template @skyscanner/backpack --use-npm
```

This is the error I am getting,

```
D:\SKYSCANNER INTERNSHIP>npx create-react-app@3.4.1 my-app --scripts-version=@skyscanner/backpack-react-scripts --template @skyscanner/backpack --use-npm

Creating a new React app in D:\SKYSCANNER INTERNSHIP\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and @skyscanner/backpack-react-scripts with @skyscanner/cra-template-backpack...

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\SKYSCANNER INTERNSHIP\my-app\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\SKYSCANNER INTERNSHIP\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'D:\\SKYSCANNER INTERNSHIP\\my-app\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',`your text`
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]``your text``
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.18.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if "python3" can be used
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "python3" to get executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if "python" can be used
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "python" to get executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executable path is "C:\Python27\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Python27\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - version is "2.7.18"
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - version is 2.7.18 - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 3
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "py.exe" to get Python 3 executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executable path is "C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - version is "3.12.0"
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.0 found at "C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 18.18.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '18.18.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "18.18.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 18.18.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 18.18.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: D:\SKYSCANNER INTERNSHIP\my-app\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? Yes
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS checking VS2022 (17.7.34031.279) found at:
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS "D:\vs code"
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2022 (17.7.34031.279) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "D:\vs code"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (D:\SKYSCANNER INTERNSHIP\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\SKYSCANNER INTERNSHIP\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (D:\SKYSCANNER INTERNSHIP\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\SKYSCANNER INTERNSHIP\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\SKYSCANNER INTERNSHIP\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\SKYSCANNER INTERNSHIP\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\SKYSCANNER INTERNSHIP\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:430:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:303:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\SKYSCANNER INTERNSHIP\\my-app\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\SKYSCANNER INTERNSHIP\my-app\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.18.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Hafsa PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-10T13_13_52_939Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom @skyscanner/backpack-react-scripts @skyscanner/cra-template-backpack has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from D:\SKYSCANNER INTERNSHIP
Done.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
npm init react-app my-app --scripts-version=@skyscanner/backpack-react-scripts --template @skyscanner/backpack --use-npm
```